# Save special character

Tags: php, mysql

I have this piece of PHP code:

```
$bd_to = mysqli_connect($to_mysql_hostname, $to_mysql_user, $to_mysql_password, $to_mysql_db);
if (!$bd_to) {
    die('database to | Connect Error: ' . mysqli_connect_errno());
}

$data = ["Gener","Febrer",'Març',"Abril","Maig","Juny","Juliol","Agost","Setembre","Octubre","Novembre","Desembre"];
for ($counter = 0; $counter < count($data) ; $counter++){
    $insert = "INSERT INTO estancia_mes(mes, numero) VALUES ('" . mysqli_real_escape_string($bd_to, $data[$counter]) . "', " . ($counter+1) . ")";
    $result = mysqli_query($bd_to, $insert);

    if (!$result){
        echo "error: " . mysqli_error($bd_to) . "\n";
        echo "\n" . $insert . "\n";
        return;
    }
}
echo "inserted rows to Estancia_mes table\n";
```

The problem is with the string `"Març"` because when it do the insert the value is upload as `MarÃ§`, so there is a problem with `ç` character.

The database has a **utf8_spanish_ci** collation.

If I edit manually the value and change `Ã§` to `ç` it works (using a Desktop program -> HeidiSQL). Could be that PHP is not sending `ç` and is sending `Ã§`?

This php script is executed by Windows CMD

Comment: try changing it to utf8_unicode_ci.

Comment: utf8_encode(mysqli_real_escape_string($bd_to, $data[$counter]))

Comment: change it to utf8_general_ci

Comment: Can you alter your database?

Comment: I have done something similar for French, and I ended up transfering all special characters into HTML entities notation and storing that.  It was simpler for me since all this was displayed in a web page anyway.

Comment: yeah, but this months array with not display in html

Comment: @Aymenbz I have tested to change to utf8_general_ci  but the same

Comment: @Roy your solution give me `MarÃƒÂ§`

Comment: I can alter my database @MarcAudet

Comment: @albert sorry, is decode... utf8_decode(mysqli_real_escape_string($bd_to, $data[$counter]))

Comment: @albert also make sure you have `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">` to ensure the browse will use the proper encode.

Comment: this `mysqli_set_charset ( $bd_to , "utf8" );` solved all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `$bd_to->set_charset("utf8");` after connecting. So that would be

```
$bd_to = mysqli_connect($to_mysql_hostname, $to_mysql_user, $to_mysql_password, $to_mysql_db);
$bd_to->set_charset("utf8");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the database, you could alter the character set and the collation.

For the character set, try `utf8mb4`
and for the collation `utf8mb4_spanish_ci`

This approach is easier than changing the encoding on the fly.  (I have used both in the past.)

The multi-byte character set will take care of any special characters including emojis.

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-unicode-sets.html

Comment: If you can, try phpMyAdmin, it lists all the available options.  I happen to use SQLyog (I don't suggest that you buy it).  You could make the change from the command line (a bit more work).

Answer (score 0):

After test your solutions in the comments, and see that the problem was not solved, I was thinking that the problem should not be the mySQL database, but the characters PHP is sending to it.

So I have looked for configuring the charset of the php queries and I have found he function

```
bool mysqli_set_charset ( mysqli $link , string $charset )
```

> Sets the default character set to be used when sending data from and to the database server.

So after opening the connection with mySQL I added:

```
mysqli_set_charset ( $bd_to , "utf8" );
```

[More info about the function (PHP.net)](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php)